# mlxtend libary not working on AWS-Sagemaker after installing it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Inspite of installing the module "mlxtend" for Apriori ( Market basket analysis)
in conda packages and updated it.

### Got the below error

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import mlxtend
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlxtend'

Comment: Have you tried `!pip install mlxtend` in a notebook cell? See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-add-external.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a member of the SageMaker team; thank you for trying out the service!

Have you made sure that you installed mlxtend in the same conda environment that you are running your code under? For example, if you are running your code under the "python3" environment, you would install mlxtend in that environment with a command like "conda install -n python3 -c conda-forge mlxtend".